# Jquery autocomplete - when select an item the cursor move to begining

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery for autocomplete and when the user select any item from the dropdown list , the cursor of the input text move to the left (begining of the input text).

The input text is not read only because I want to enable the user to enter text and not only select.

here is my code:

```
 $("#id").autocomplete({        
    source: url,
    select:  function (event, ui) {
               // some code here
    }
});
```

This behavior is not correct.
I need that the cursor will stay at the end of the selected item and
NOT move to the start.

Thanks for any help,

John.

Comment: So, you want to move the cursor to the beginning of your input? What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin to move the cursor on the select event
https://gist.github.com/1007907

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this behaviour. Here is a fiddle to explain how I have tested : http://jsfiddle.net/S77xa/62/

Answer (score 0):

this is usually a problem when you have not focused the element before. Try to use

```
$("#id").focus();
```

on select.

Comment: didn't help.
I have also tried to add autoFocus: true to the autocomplete 
also didn't help.